# is it possible to generate uml or jdl model from existing jhipster project

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

after generating j hipster project is it possible generate JDL model or uml diagram from the generated code in order to see how the application is build and relations between classes.

Answer (score 7):

run the following command `jhipster export-jdl <<FILE_NAME_PATH>>`

Comment: While this command might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your answer does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in your answer and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just run `yo jhipster:export-jdl` to generate a JDL file of your current project.

Comment: thank you , but it generated empty file with only this comment : // JDL definition for application 'jhipster' generated with command 'yo jhipster:export-jdl'

Comment: OK, but did you have any entity in your project? Check if the `.jhipster` directory is empty or not

Comment: now i understand taht jhispter dont consider user created by default by jhispter es entity , even afrter adding another entity related to the user entity the user entity is illustrated emty , and it doesnt exist in .jhipster project. if you can explain why this choice is made by jhispter developpers .

Answer (score 0):

As you can't import the user entity again it makes no sense to me to have it exported to a jdl file.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking jHipster from Yeoman has been deprecated. Please use JHipster CLI. `jhipster export-jdl <<FILENAME.jdl>>`.